# How to create a different theme specific 404 page in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, 404-page

I have **two themes** called desktop and iphone.
In desktop the 404 page is created in the admin side cms page.
How can I create **another 404 error page for the iphone theme** only?
so that I can put some information for the iphone theme only.

Answer (score 1):

Put the content in one page and hide the portion which is not appropriate on iphone.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348589/magento-different-home-page-for-each-theme-but-using-same-store-view-and-with) link for better explanation.